# DoubleClick Ads not working with Manifest File

Tags: javascript, html, manifest, double-click

I'm building an HTML5 app that uses Google Doubleclick ads.  99% of the app is dynamically built with JS, but the ads are hardcoded into the html like so:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-3664602748600160");
GS_googleEnableAllServices();
GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-3664602748600160", "125x125");
GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-3664602748600160", "250x250");
GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-3664602748600160", "160x600");
GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-3664602748600160", "468x60"); 
GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>

<div id="ads" style="float:right;">

<div id="square" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        GA_googleFillSlot("250x250");
    </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="small_square" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        GA_googleFillSlot("125x125");
    </script>
    </div>
</div>   
<div id="tall_banner" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        GA_googleFillSlot("160x600");
    </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="half_banner" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        GA_googleFillSlot("468x60");
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

These ads are then hidden/shifted as needed to fill the various ad spots on the generated pages.  When i implemented a manifest file to cache persistent assets i get a message that it has failed to load the http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js file.  Knowing this, I tried saving a local copy of that js file and including it in the manifest, but this led to errors regarding the GA_googleblahlah calls being undefined which seems to indicate a load order issue of some sort.  Is there some way to exempt this file from cache?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.  Using a wildcard in the network area after defining the cached elements seems to have fixed the issue.  My manifest file now looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
/js/jquery.min.js
/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
/etc
NETWORK:
*
```

Thanks to Ben Poole for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a file to cache you add it to the `NETWORK:` section of your manifest file. From [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html):

> The line marked NETWORK: is the beginning of the “online whitelist”
>   section. Resources in this section are never cached and are not
>   available offline. (Attempting to load them while offline will result
>   in an error.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, even when i move it to the whitelist i get the same GA_googlefillslot() is undefined message which seems to point towards a load order issue.